# Batch getting many bitmap resources on Android

Tags: android, resources

I have a long series of graphics -- icon1_0.png, icon1_1.png, icon1_2.png..., icon12_0.png, icon12_1.png, icon12_2.png -- and I'd like to package them with my android application.  Ideally I think I should be able to load them as resources but the resource id's are set up as java identifiers.  Of course, java identifiers can't be assembled at runtime.  I have to ask for R.drawable.icon12_00 so I cannot set up a loop

```
for(int icon=0;icon<12;icon++)
 for(int frame=0;frame<3;frame++)
  //syntax error obviously
  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable."icon" + icon + "_" + frame + ".png");
```

So is there any way to get resources by their names?  Better yet, is there a canonical way outside the resource system to pack data files into an android application package so that I can get at them?

I'm thinking about reflection but that doesn't seem like the right solution to me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `getResources().getIdentifier()` from your `Context` (e.g., `Activity`), but please cache the result if you will use it more than once. `getIdentifier()` is implemented on [`Resources`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html).

Comment: Okay, this works.  getIdentifier("resname", "restype", "com.domain.appname"); Thank you.

Comment: Instead passing package name as static value, you can use `getPackageName()`

Answer (score 6):

I know you've found an answer already, but if you use reflection then you will see a good speed increase, as getIdentifier() is slower.  I wrote about how to do the reflection method [here](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2009/12/dynamically-retrieving-resources-in.html).  However, this only works if you're accessing your own resources.

Comment: How about that.  This is a little faster.  It's a shame, though, because reflection is notoriously pokey so getIdentifier must be monster slow.

Answer (score 2):

Reflection is also very slow, you should just create an array with all of your identifies in it.

Comment: Do you mean, just write the whole loop out in code?  Or something more clever?  I'd be interested in the latter, because it would be a nice speed boost if I could get a resource even faster than using reflection (but this would be in a slightly different circumstance, where app data refers to resources - not in code).

Comment: @DanielLew he is saying you have a code generator which writes the whole loop out in code for you