# How to set ImageView by file name from object data to existing image in Drawable folder?

Tags: android

I need to call the filename and set to ImageView but it does not working at all. I knew the code below is totally wrong:

```
holder.iconFilename.setImageDrawable(subjects.getIconFilename());
```

How to call it correctly? All the **images** that need to be call were in Drawable folder.

---

My full code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SubjectAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    context = holder.itemView.getContext();
    Subjects subjects = subjectsList.get(position);
    holder.iconFilename.setImageDrawable(subjects.getIconFilename()); // Definitely wrong.
    holder.subjectNameStd.setText(subjects.getSubjectNameStd());
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent gotoChapter = new Intent (context,ChapterActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(gotoChapter);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What does `subjects.getIconFilename()` return, exactly?

Comment: filename - type: String @CommonsWare

Comment: Thanks, but what relationship does that string have to anything? I do not know what "All the icon_filename(s) I have put in Drawable folder" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've updated the question.

Comment: Do you mean that you have drawable resources like `res/drawable/something.xml`, and `getIconFilename()` returns `something.xml`?

Comment: Yes..exactly...that's what I meant.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2414165/115145

Comment: `int drawableId=holder.itemView.getResources().getIdentifier((subjects.getIconFilename(), "drawable", holder.itemView.getPackageName());`

Problem at `holder.itemView.getPackageName()`.How?

Comment: `getPackageName()` is a method on `Context`. You have one, called `context`.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare for helping me..you save my time.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you have images as resources like this: res/drawable/whatever, then you load it into the ImageView like this:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.whatever);
```

That's a pretty standard text book thing. You are probably missing something else.

For example, your holder.iconFilename look suspicious. Your holder should have a property that's an ImageView, not a file name, e.g. holder.fooImageView.

The other potential problem that you are not explaining is what Subjects is. It should return the resource id, e.g. subjects.getPhotoResourceId(). If you are trying to load your refernences to the drawable resource from a database or other external source, you need to create a mapping from an external constant to the R.drawable.whatever constant.

```
For example:
if (subjects.getStatusId() == OK_STATUS) {
  holder.statusImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok_icon);
}
```